# Why does $2^{-x}$ equal $0.5^x$?

Tags: exponentiation

My son mistaken to answer his math question: $2^{-x} = 0.5^{x}$
He said this must be false, I asked ChatGpt but still not satisfied with the answer because I want to explain to my son at age 12.

The strange part is: when you look at $2^{-x}$ the result of Y must be negative while $0.5^x$ is positive.

Comment: "The result of $Y$ must be negative" is false. Is $2^{-1}$ negative?

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't understand math.

Comment: Don't use chatGPT for math. In fact, don't use chatGPT. It's a stochastic parrot with no understanding.

Comment: $$2^{-x} = \frac{1}{2^x} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x = 0.5^x$$

Comment: Think about the sequence $2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4,...$. To move forward in this sequence you multiply by $2$; to move backward you divide by $2$. What do you get when you move backwards past $2^0$? Remember that dividing by $2$ is the same as multiplying by $\frac12$.

Comment: Are you aware that $2^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}=0.5$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$a^{-b} = \dfrac {1}{a^b} = \bigg ( \dfrac {1}{a} \bigg )^b$$ See also Robert Israel's comment.

Comment: This is helpful

Answer (score 1):

The main part of $2^{-n}$ is to understand $2^{-1}.$ $a^{-1}$ is generally the solution of the equation $a\cdot x=1,$ i.e. the inverse element to $a$ with respect to multiplication. $x=a^{-1}$ is how we write this element. Hence, $2^{-1}$ solves $2\cdot x =1$ which makes $2^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{2}.$ Finally,
$$
2^{-n}=\left(2^{-1}\right)^n=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n=0.5^n=\dfrac{1}{2^n}>0
$$

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation, can you provide example for n = -1,-2?

Comment: If $n<0$ then $-n>0$ and we get $2^{-n}=\underbrace{2\cdot\ldots\cdot 2}_{-n\text{ times}}.$ If you meant examples like $2^{-3}$ then we have $2^{-3}=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^3=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{8}.$